# Error 310 upon adding rsvp_event permission

Tags: php, facebook, events, user-permissions

I'm trying to figure out how to rsvp to events, I was able to connect and get to my main page before adding the 'rsvp_event' permission to the code according to this: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#attending

Not sure why its giving me the error.

```
//check if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user
//if not then redirect them again to facebook's permissions page
$permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'manage_pages', 'create_event','rsvp_event');
foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) {
    if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 ) {
        $login_url_params = array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages',
            'fbconnect' =>  1,
            'display'   =>  "page",
            'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
        header("Location: {$login_url}");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the text of the error?

Comment: Look at your `scope`. You aren't ever asking for the `rsvp_event` permission.

Comment: @Igy, based on a quick search..it's too many redirects...

Comment: @cpilko ah that was it, wasn't asking the permissions in the scope. Thank you

Comment: @ifaour - HTTP 310 likely isn't the same as Facebook's error code 310, but i guess the OP's app could be doing an infinite redirect loop?

Comment: @Igy I think so...on a side note, is `fbconnect`, `display` mean anything in the new SDK? Also for the OP, the SDK will construct the `next` link for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code to future proof your app against future changes:

```
'scope' => implode(',', $permissions_needed),
```

Comment: Plus, this is nicer: `if( !array_key_exists($perm, $permissions['data'][0]) ) {`